# How to work with Selenium's Chrome initialized by php exec() command?

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, exec

I try to start python script by php command exec().

Python script started by root-user in SSH and activated virtual environment working perfect. But the same python script starting by php command exec() give errors.

Please show me right direction to resolving problem.

Py-script is the Selenium-based script working with Chrome.

exec()'s output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Проход  0
    [1] => Traceback (most recent call last):
    [2] =>   File "/var/www/html/calltracking_parser/parser.py", line 156, in 
    [3] =>     driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options,
    [4] =>   File "/var/www/html/calltracking_parser/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
    [5] =>     super().__init__(
    [6] =>   File "/var/www/html/calltracking_parser/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    [7] =>     super().__init__(
    [8] =>   File "/var/www/html/calltracking_parser/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    [9] =>     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    [10] =>   File "/var/www/html/calltracking_parser/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    [11] =>     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    [12] =>   File "/var/www/html/calltracking_parser/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    [13] =>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    [14] =>   File "/var/www/html/calltracking_parser/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    [15] =>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    [16] => selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
    [17] =>   (chrome not reachable)
    [18] =>   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
    [19] => Stacktrace:
    [20] => #0 0x5566b630f4e3 
    [21] => #1 0x5566b603ec76 
    [22] => #2 0x5566b6067d78 
    [23] => #3 0x5566b6064029 
    [24] => #4 0x5566b60a2ccc 
    [25] => #5 0x5566b60a247f 
    [26] => #6 0x5566b6099de3 
    [27] => #7 0x5566b606f2dd 
    [28] => #8 0x5566b607034e 
    [29] => #9 0x5566b62cf3e4 
    [30] => #10 0x5566b62d33d7 
    [31] => #11 0x5566b62ddb20 
    [32] => #12 0x5566b62d4023 
    [33] => #13 0x5566b62a21aa 
    [34] => #14 0x5566b62f86b8 
    [35] => #15 0x5566b62f8847 
    [36] => #16 0x5566b6308243 
    [37] => #17 0x7f4e6dafd609 start_thread
    [38] =>
)
```

Py-script starting with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--window-size=2560,1440')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options, desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get(url)
```

PHP-file starting py-script:

```
require_once 'backend/functions.php';

$test = exec(__DIR__.'/env/bin/python '.__DIR__.'/parser.py 2>&1', $output, $result_code);
show($output);
```